# Exclamation mark and assignment inside of a function

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain why this:

```
def do_something str
  str = "bar"
end
​
str_main = "foo"
do_something str_main
​
puts str_main
```

displays `foo`?

And this:

```
def do_something str
  str.capitalize!
end
​
str_main = "foo"
do_something str_main
​
puts str_main
```

displays `Foo`?

Comment: That's not "equality", btw. That's assignment (to a new local variable)

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find a good reference answer for this. It surely exists. Community, maybe you know.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the way Ruby passes arguments.

When the method is being called, you have two references, `str_main` and `str`, to the same object  `"foo"`.

In the first example, when you use `str = "bar"`, you are just changing what the `str` reference points to. So now you have `str_main -> "foo"` and `str -> "bar"`. Therefore, the original object is not changed.

In the second example, you didn't change the `str` reference and changed the string in place with a [mutator method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21), thus changing the same object that `str_main` points to.

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation mark or bang operator modifies the original value. It is a destructive method. For example, let's say you had a string

```
string = "hi";
```

If you call the `upcase` method, you will get the following

```
string.upcase
=> "HI"
```

However, if you call string again, you will get the initial value.

```
string
=> "hi"
```

Now, let's say you use the destructive method `upcase!`

```
string.upcase!
=> "HI"
```

Now, if you call string again, you will see that the value was mutated.

```
string
=> "HI"
```

Comment: The exclamation mark doesn't modify anything and it's not an operator. (There *is* a `!` operator, but it is prefix not postfix.) It's simply part of the method name.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, references are passed by value.  So, a reference to `str_main` is passed to method `do_something`, a copy of reference is present in variable `str`.

This, however, does not mean that value that is referred to by both variables also has been copied around - there is still a single copy of referred to value, which is the string defined in `Main`.

Hence, when you assign a new value to `str`, this does not alter the value of `str_main`.  However, when you modify the value that is referred by `str`, its changes are visibble outside.

Answer (score 1):

All ruby methods return the last thing evaluated. However, object assignment stays within the scope of the current code block. Assigning `str_main` to a new value within a method will not affect `str_main`, unless it was an instance variable (`@str_main`). Doing such allows you to reassign an object across scopes, or depths, of your program. This is why your first method outputs `'foo'` instead of `'bar'`.

Now, the second example. [`#capitalize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-capitalize) is a method called on a string object. It returns a *new `String` instance*, where its value is original object capitalized.

```
string = 'foobar'
string.capitalize  # => 'Foobar'
puts string  # => 'foobar'
```

Notice how `string` is only modified temporarily, and when called again it is back to normal.

Many methods in ruby have counterparts ending in `!`. This convention is the same as: `object = object.some_method`. Instead of creating a *new instance* of an object, these methods edit the original object's value. In the case of [`#capitalize!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21), the string is capitalized *and* modified for future calls.

```
string = 'foo'
string.capitalize!  # => 'Foo'
puts string  # => 'Foo'
```

Back to your second example. Using the `#capitalize!` method within the scope of `do_something` allows you to modify the `str_main` object. In a similar way to making `str_main` an instance variable.